# WebMethod not working when given a large string parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

Does anybody know whether there is any issue with json object if a lengthy string object is passed.

I'm calling a webmethod with its content as encoded html data. The string generated is around 7000 in count and this is not getting passed to the webmethod from the clientside. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

**Sol 1:One more thing you can do is check for the Compression like Gzip which may reduce your content size.**

**sol 2:**
check this config property maxStringContentLength and maxBytesPerRead. Also make sure that whatever binding configuration you set up, you're actually using it in all the right places.

Following link may resolve your issue :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/c2a770ed-a7ff-4c9e-a318-8b86b2f59a85